# using source("X.R") in Sweave file

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I need to use a function in my Sweave file to execute chunk codes.
For example, I have function `MEAN <- function(x) mean(x)` in my directory, then I want use the chunk code

```
x=c(1,2,3,4)
MEAN(x)
```

in my Sweave file.
Does anyone know how can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are writing code normally inside the code blocks of the document, just make sure to set the directory of where the R file is located and source the file.

e.g.,

```
<<echo=TRUE>>=
    setwd(mydirectory)
    source(myfile)
    print(MEAN(x))
@
```